# How do I word my resignation?

Tags: resignation

My current supervisor happens to be the owner of the company and, although this person's position and education are nowhere near what we do as a department, this person is still considered our supervisor.

I decided to switch jobs because I don't like how things are done here.  There's no protocol; there's no true organization within the department; we have no say nor final word in any matter, although we were hired to make some sort of decisions along the way. Everything must be passed to my supervisor before even considering any changes, no matter how unimportant the topic is (compared to other big decisions or changes)  [This person lacks the field knowledge to be making these types of decisions, so we end up with a lot of decisions made up from personal opinions, rather than from a professional perspective].

There's micromanaging and then there's this supervisor's micromanaging. The entire department is annoyed by this, but no one says anything, because the supervisor can't take any type of criticism or comments or suggestions, and gets easily offended (basically everyone is scared of the boss/owner).

There's also the issue that this supervisor needs to know every single detail of our lives (not as gossip but as a way to keep track of us) and questions our decisions of our personal lives, which I dislike a lot.

I've always seen this person as a very good entrepreneur and business person. But the lack of knowledge from the supervisor's part about the things we do in the department cloud my impressions of this person as a team leader. I have a lot of respect for this person but the way things are handled in this particular company are not matching my expectations and make me feel uncomfortable.

The reasons above are pretty rough things to say, not to mention sensitive topics, but these are the reasons I want to leave. My question is, ***How do I express or bring up these issues without offending this person and without things getting heated up?***

Comment: I think you should first read what people might do with this kind of information here: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/60475/how-do-exit-interviews-benefit-the-company

Comment: This sounds almost exactly the the situation I was in a year ago. Do as all the answers suggest - don't make it personal, don't give unnecessary details. Do not under any circumstances "bring up these issues" - particularly not written in a resignation letter. He's not going to change just because you're resigning.

Comment: "How do I express/bring up these issues without offending this person or without things getting heated up?" - You're leaving so if your only limitation is being offensive then that is a minor point considering you'll be removed from the situation itself in 2 weeks.

Comment: I would refer you to [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/changing-employers-the-right-way/1075), especially [this answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1075), which have a ton of great notes on this subject.

Comment: Providing constructive criticism is a nice idea in theory (which is why people do exit interview), **but as you've quit there's pretty much no incentive for you to provide it and it might be received badly**. Also, imho, part of a company being open and responsive to criticism is seeking it out before people quit. -- A lot of answers focus on the letter. Bear in mind that, unless your boss is unavailable for a face-to-face meeting, your letter isn't actually the way you inform them of your resignation, **it's simply a written confirmation of a conversation you've already had**.

Comment: see also: [Should letter of resignation be honest or formal?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/42321/should-letter-of-resignation-be-honest-or-formal)

Comment: the resignation letter only contains that: your resignation. Plus the date, possibly detailing the notice period. Everything else can be discussed during the exit interview, if there is one, but that's only if you want to give your impressions.

Comment: @Just Do It Could you tell us your region? There seems to be some cultural differences on these things between for example Europe and the US.

Comment: And how would I go about that conversation @NathanCooper ?

Comment: Latin America @LisaMM

Comment: @JustDoIt ahhhhh, that's why that was just a comment. I'll write an answer if I feel I have something to add.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

**You don't.**

For a resignation letter, try something like.

```
Boss,
I am resigning effective (some date in the near future, usually 2 weeks)

Best wishes,
Just Do It
```

Leave out the politics, leave out the feedback, leave out the emotion.

**Don't burn bridges**.

You don't know what the future will bring - five years from now you might need a favor from this person.

Comment: I would usually do that, but I do mention that this person always wants to know details, and always questions

Comment: +1 I was about to write the same answer. One point maybe to add: "Suck it up, behave professional and leave them with smile"

Comment: @JustDoIt One of the reasons you are resigning is because this person always wants to know details.  This is your chance to say no - just do it.

Comment: Just because the person wants to know details doesn't mean they have a right to them.

Comment: @JustDoIt Resigning itself is a great way to say you don't like it there and if they can't figure out why then they'll probably be unwilling to change as what they are doing is obviously working for them. Just say you wish to resign and chances are they won't even ask for a reason and just wish you well.

Comment: OTOH, suggesting the OP to not say anything is probably another contributing factor to why things always stay the same everywhere? Context might also be important: Is the boss of the boss aware of the situation and just turning a blind eye? Or does he simply not know that the problem exists and would've (perhaps) done something had he known about it sooner/at all? Is there *really* nothing someone can do, other than just leave silently?

Comment: Another angle, what could you say to satisfy the employers need for details in a way you provide feedback? That wat the employer might to something about it. What can you say? Maybe say you'll write a small e-mail about it, so you ca think about what you want to say (and then first make someone else read it)?

Comment: "More formal" companies usually have some sort of exit process (interview or fill-out forms) that are supposed to collect reasons for employee turn-over, and **maybe** start changes to prevent others leaving if warranted. In all cases the terse notice like above is the norm, upon which such process is started (in addition). If your boss wants details after the notice, then that is his (informal) "exit process" and that can be handled via a chat or a separate written document, if you so wish. He can't really force you, and you can respectfully decline to divulge particulars.

Answer (score 27):

> ***How do I express/bring up these issues without offending this person or without things getting heated up?***

You don't. You certainly don't write it down in an official document like your letter of resignation.

If your boss decides to have an exit interview with you and inquires as to why you're leaving, I would still avoid going negative. You're highly likely to offend and burn bridges. You should always do your best to leave every position/co-worker/former boss on good terms. It's a small world.

Instead, I would keep it to generics.

> I don't feel like the company is the right fit for me.

when pressed

> I was presented with another opportunity that I felt was best for myself and my career.

(you do have something else lined up, right?)

Answer (score 3):

### Being honest does not benefit anyone here

As you were already told by two others:

- **Do not write anything more into resignation than required**

Aim on factual resignation letter. For instance under Czech work law it is required to say

> Boss,
>
> I hereby resign for my job as XXX
>
> My last day of work will be dd.mm.yyy (last day of leaving period)
>
> Signed in This town
>
> (Date, signature and name in written)

- **When pressed to provide more info, provide white lies**

Examples:

- I was presented with offer from random headhunter I cannot turn down. It is for (local famous company) earning (double your current salary)

*Why double? Because you do not want to be in situation where your current boss offers you higher amount of money if you stay, do you?*

- I am moving out of town

[Leaving interviews do not benefit anyone](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/60475/how-do-exit-interviews-benefit-the-company) so do not expect that even carefully worded resignation reasons which are true will provide any change to the better.

And even if it would, it does not help **you**, does it?

Comment: -1 for white lies. They can bite you and they're unnecessary. Just decline to say anything more than you need to.

Comment: I understand you. But if you cannot resist your pushy boss who demands to know and you feel you are unable to get away wirth simple "no" some white lie is good walk away...

Comment: At the very least, both example white lies are terrible, in that they are easily uncovered.

Comment: Well, not a big fan of lies but when I do end up resigning I am indeed moving out of town, 600 miles out of town to be precise

Comment: DO NOT LIE. The only subject where white lies are appropriate in professional communication is your feelings. It might sound cool to have your boss tell everyone you've left for Netflix. But how cool is it going to be when they rush to connect to you on LinkedIn and your profile lists Burger World?