# Should I tell my employer that I'm looking for a new job or just give a two weeks notice?

Tags: new-job

I'm transferring to a new school and it is an hour from my current school. That means, I will be too far from my current employer. Ideally I would like to find a new job between May and September (near to the new school). However, I am happy with my current employer and I have no problems with anyone. Should I tell them that I am looking for a new job due to the long commute to the new school, or would it be better to put in my two weeks notice out of the blue?

Comment: Are those your only options? Would your current employer support working remotely (with maybe a day in the office every so often)?

Comment: No I work in a warehouse, no remote positions. So those are my only options, and I want to move on from my current job.

Comment: see also: [How to gracefully quit from a job/company I like (better offer elsewhere)?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23423/how-to-gracefully-quit-from-a-job-company-i-like-better-offer-elsewhere)

Comment: How would it benefit you if you tell the company that you want to leave? It doesn't. How could it hurt you? There are many ways; for example if you tell them tomorrow, you might be out of a job the next day (or two weeks later, or whatever your notice period is).

Comment: The only benefit I could see is using your current employer as a reference.

Comment: @DavidK: Presumably you could do that without giving them a heads up that you are on your way out.

Comment: @NotMe How can you ask someone to be a reference without letting them know you're looking for a new job?

Comment: @DavidK: Ah, you meant for the current job hunt.  okay, that makes far more sense.

Answer (score 11):

I'll let you in on a "secret." (That really isn't one.)

Competent managers know the difference between an employee who's taking some classes and a student who works some to pay their bills.  Your manager should know you're in the second category, and is and always has been prepared for the day you move on.

I have techs who work for me in my department.  They're right out of college, and they're looking for their first "real" job not working a support desk.  I know this, and they know I know this.  No one is trying to pretend it isn't what's going on.  They're looking, I'm giving references, and I know that every now and then one will find that job they're looking for and move on.  All I'm looking for from them is to do good work until that time comes.

Your manager should accept your two weeks' notice, shake your hand, wish you well, and ask you if you know of someone at your school, now, who'd be a good fit to take your place.

You're not breaking up with a romantic interest.  This is a job, and everyone knew it was a temporary situation.

Find your new job, give the notice, and try to keep everything as positive as possible.  I think you're going to be surprised as to how smooth this will actually go.