# Is it right to leave one job for another?

Tags: quitting

I like my current job.  They pay well and my co-workers are awesome. I was just offered a position at another company, more pay, less hours and it's 2 minutes from my home.  My current job is a 20 min drive one way.

I don't know if I should take the chance on going to the new job and not liking the new co-workers.   I'm so afraid to tell my current boss that I quit because I heard they are real jerks to people that quit.  I'm just scared and confused.  Any help or ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to gracefully quit from a job/company I like (better offer elsewhere)?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23423/how-to-gracefully-quit-from-a-job-company-i-like-better-offer-elsewhere)

Comment: You say `my co-workers are awesome` but then you also say `I heard they are real jerks to people that quit`. If you leave the job in the right way (proper notice, etc.) and they are jerks about it, there isn't anything awesome about that.

Comment: I'm not very old (16 years old, so basically completely wrong at this stack exchange) but I would at least meet the coworkers of the other company. I would never leave a company without checking out the new one. Maybe call them, go to dinner with the employees of the company and when you like them you safely switch jobs.

Answer (score 6):

You have to do what is right for you. Despite how you feel about your company and your co-workers, your job is never secure and all it takes is one year of low profit margins for a suit to take your job away.

If you leave the right way (2 weeks notice, re-assign duties, etc.) and your boss/coworkers still treat you like dirt, then I would re-assess how "good" they are. People leave for other jobs. That's how free markets work.

Answer (score 4):

Nobody can tell you whether or not it's right to leave somewhere and join somewhere else. That has to come from you.

That being said, if there's more pay for less hours and it's closer to your home, then why wouldn't you consider it?

What would you lose by interviewing? If you get it, then you'll have better working conditions, if you don't get it, then you're still in a job you enjoy. It's win-win as far as I can see.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm so afraid to tell my current boss that I quit because I heard they are real jerks to people that quit.

Don't let that bother you. In fact it should count against staying put; do you want to carry on working for that bully type of employer?

No one's happy when a good employee leaves, but they should be happy for you, wish you luck and thank you for the time you have put in. Not make you feel like the last X years have been wasted and treat you like a traitor, because you're not.

Answer (score 1):

You will almost certainly have to switch jobs at some point in your career.

So if you are concerned about the fact that your current employers “are real jerks to people that quit” it would seem better to quit earlier than not, while you can do it on your own terms, with a job lined up and less concern about having a reference from them.

Answer (score 0):

Your co-workers may be awesome - at present. That doesn't mean they are going to be so forever. It is best to consider that as a temporary situation that can easily change. Some of them may leave or move to another office or department and may be replaced by people who are no so agreeable. Or there may be a new project or a new policy which generates intense competition among co-workers in your team. That can easily change how people treat each other. Besides if you are good friends with your co-workers you can still keep in touch with them even after you move to a different company. So it is not a great idea to consider agreeable co-workers as a major factor when deciding whether to take up a new job.

> ...I heard they are real jerks to people that quit.

If your boss is the type who is going to treat you badly if you quit, that itself is a reason to quit. Do you want to spend your days working for this person so that he (or she) can get ahead in his life? It is better not to work for such a  boss. That will benefit both your career and personal life.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you *will* leave your current company at some point. That is a fundamental property of the modern workplace.

Secondly, if the other place is willing to pay you more for less hours, that means your market value is higher than your current salary.

Thirdly, coworkers are usually pretty decent. However, you can always ask the new company if you can meet some of the people that you would be working with. If they won't let you, that's often a red flag.