# How to quit your job gracefully?

Tags: resignation

Soon I may quit my job. I was wondering about how to do it gracefully.

Here is something I would say when quitting:

"Working here has been great and I really have nothing in particular that bothered me. The other offer I have received offers me higher pay and more benefits. Also, I think that being exposed to a different team with a different project is going to allow me to learn new things. Again, working here has been great and I can't pinpoint my leaving to one particular reason, but I'm being offered a higher salary with better benefits for a similar job."

Do you think this is appropriate? What other things would you take note of when quitting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to gracefully quit from a job/company I like (better offer elsewhere)?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23423/how-to-gracefully-quit-from-a-job-company-i-like-better-offer-elsewhere)

Comment: You can just say that you are greatful  for the experience and now it's the time to try something new.  Unless you want your current employer to counteroffer there's no need to   mention salary or benefits.  Keep it short and sweet.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to say anything more than "I resign, my last day will be X" - or put another way, what's your actual goal here?

Comment: When you keep saying "there really is no particular reason that bothered me", it makes it sound like there is. Keep it short like others have recommended.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, I guess the OP is likely new in the work force, and the OP simply wants to maintain a good business relationship with the old boss and old company after leaving.

Comment: @Pointer_to_void, From your first question (posted 23 days ago) to this second question, I assume that you have already got the job offer after returning from the vacation. So, congratulations. :-)

Comment: If you talk about being offered a higher salary, it will sound like you're trying to blackmail your employer into giving you a pay rise.  Don't do that, unless that really is your intention.  I would recommend that you don't mention having a higher salary, unless they specifically ask.

Answer (score 24):

1. Why would you mention anything about the new job and salary? Don't.
2. You don't need to justify why you're leaving nor do you need to explain why you're leaving. Don't.
3. Keep it short, simple, and professional.

> "I've decided to leave to pursue other career opportunities. I've
> enjoyed my time here. Thank you."

Answer (score 1):

1. Read up on your paperwork and contract. Make sure you know what the notice periods are and what happens to bonuses, stock options, benefits, unemployment, etc.
2. Explore ways to salvage the current gig. Ask about promotions, raises, different roles, or whatever you find attractive. There is no harm in asking nicely and you never know what will happen
3. Find a new job, work out the timing in accordance with step 1
4. Prep BEFORE you resign. Make sure you are aware of what needs to be transferred. Untangle data from private and business devices, make sure you have copies of important emails or documents that are relevant for your employment status (and legal for you to have). If you have excessive personal stuff at your workplace, start discretely moving it out.
5. Write a letter of resignation. Keep it very simple: "I resign from corporation XYZ effective ABC. In accordance to my contract my last day of work will be DEF. Thank you for the opportunity of working here". Date and sign, print two copies but DO NOT send them
6. Book a meeting with your manager or use a regular 1:1. Tell your that you are resigning. Keep it very friendly and simple. "Boss it's been great working here and I'm grateful for the opportunity that I had the collaboration, but it's time for me to move and I've decided to resign". Hand over the letter: one for you boss and one for HR. Send an email up with the identical text to your boss and to HR directly after the meeting.
7. You may get questions or be pushed about this. It's up to you how deep you want to engage including "not at all". Personally I see no problem with giving constructive feedback if being asked by a reasonable and trustworthy person. I also see no problem in shutting up if it gets hostile, pushy, or if I don't like or trust the asker. "I feel the new opportunity is a better fit for my career goals". Rinse and repeat.
8. Serve your notice period well and support the transition plan, if there is any.
9. On your last day, hand in your stuff (there should be an employee departure checklist), say goodbye and walk out the door.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to explain that one of the reasons you quit is to have a higher salary and better benefits. That's not necessary.

**Most people don't go to a new company to get a lower salary or worse benefits. :-)** The reason is that they will still have to pay approximately the same amount of bills or have a **compatible** cost of living even if they work for another company.

**However, some people may go to a new company for a lower salary** if they value other important factors such as better work environment, work-life balance, living closer to family members, or getting a better fit in terms of technical stacks and **long term career goals**.

In either case, people usually don't mention the salary/benefits provided by the new company as one of official reasons to quit in the resignation letter.

So, it's a good idea keep the resignation letter short, simple, professional, and positive as user "joeqwerty" recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Your email sounds like you telling them the perks of your new job. You do not have to sell your new offer here. Unless you are trying to negotiate with your current firm wielding your new job offer.

A resignation email is not about listing out reasons why you are leaving. It is notifying people you work with about leaving.

Do not burn bridges. What your email should actually say is: that you enjoyed working with them and that you will do everything you can for a smooth transition.

Keep It Short and Simple.