# Feel Bad Leaving current job for a new one

Tags: job-change

I've been in my current role for almost 6 years with the company and been with the company for 8 years in total.  Overall they've been very good to me, given me opportunity to travel the world and have been pretty decent with raises (even paid for me to get my masters degree).  I get along great with my boss, we've argued from time to time but it's been productive.

I found out back in October that corporate (which sits in Europe) is going to be consolidating my function (not all of it, but most of it) to Eastern Europe.  This bothers me as I feel that whoever is left is going to have to pick up the pieces (goal is to have 1-2 people still in place) to this satellite group who doesn't care about the facility that I work in.  I'm not sure my job will be present in 2 years and with this consolidation the chance for advancement, from what I see, is small.  I've tried to ask around to see what is going to happen but I haven't received very much information as corporate is holding the answers close to the vest.  Furthermore, we recently initiated an early retirement for people at the facility I work at, almost half of my team falls into this and most will take it so the team will be reduced prior to my announcement of leaving.

I've recently been offered a similar position at another company for more money, I'm very interested in this position, but again feel bad for abandoning my team and my boss who I know depends on me to lead my smaller team through this transition, but I've also got to look out for myself.

I'm fairly certain I'll accept the new position as I have to look out for myself, but I'm looking for some feedback as I still feel wrong about looking & accepting a new position given the current state of my team & facility.  I know my boss is not going to be happy, but I really don't know what else to do given the current situation.

Comment: "feeling bad" isn't a question. is there a question?

Comment: `fairly certain I'll accept the new position as I have to look out for myself, but I'm looking for some feedback as I still feel wrong about looking & accepting a new position given the current state of my team & facility`... nah just do it

Comment: For more specific advice related to this, search for ''resign'' in this site and look at the existing topics. For example, http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/92/how-do-i-maintain-a-good-relationship-with-an-employer-after-resigning

Answer (score 6):

Don't feel bad.

**What you need to do:** Transition your knowledge to those who remain, document everything to the best of your ability, accept the new job, and move on with life.

Your company is unlikely to take care of you more than the minimum required by law.

Answer (score 3):

First things first, it is very normal to feel what you are feeling. Spending 40+ hours a week doing anything is going to get your emotions tied up in it, naturally.

That being said....business is business. I hate to say it, but a company's loyalty to you only exists insofar as they have the money to pay you and your function generates revenue. Beyond that, you are nothing to them. It doesn't matter that you have kids, a wife, a mortgage, etc. If there is no money, there is no job, and your boss will happily lay you off if it means he gets to stay.

Making your boss happy is no longer your priority if you are leaving this company. Being a manager comes with this territory, and you leaving might actually teach him a thing or two about his own management style (or if he also should look for another job).

Give your two weeks, make sure your job is fully in the hands of someone else and that you hand it off appropriately, keep in touch over time via emails and what not, and you will have done everything you could do.

Answer (score 3):

> I've recently been offered a similar position at another company for
>   more money, I'm very interested in this position, but again feel bad
>   for abandoning my team and my boss who I know depends on me to lead my
>   smaller team through this transition, but I've also got to look out
>   for myself.
>
> I'm fairly certain I'll accept the new position as I have to look out
>   for myself, but I'm looking for some feedback as I still feel wrong
>   about looking & accepting a new position given the current state of my
>   team & facility. I know my boss is not going to be happy, but I really
>   don't know what else to do given the current situation.

I'm not really sure what your question is here, but I'll offer some thoughts.

You have given this company 8 years. These days, that's a long tenure.

You sound convinced that you should accept the new position. In my opinion, you need to go with your gut and as you say look out for yourself.

It's difficult to leave a company when you've been there that long, and people depend on your leadership. But it doesn't sound like this part of the company is going to be whole for long anyway.

Say goodbye to your friends. Stay in touch with them. But otherwise don't feel bad about leaving.