# How best to relate to my boss, who appears betrayed following my resignation?

Tags: management, quitting

I was tired of earning less than people who got before me, doing more work than other people, and being ignored every time I asked for a raise. So after working at my company for two years without a pay increase, I resigned with a standard  30 days notice.

I talked to my boss about my exit, and everything seemed fine at the time. Now, every time he sees me, he tries to run away without talking to me. I'm feeling like he's a little hurt. He's not giving me tasks, so I have to find my own work, such as helping people out, or fixing things that can be made better.

I like my boss, so I would like to know what my options might be for maintaining our relationship for my remaining time with the company.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I maintain a good relationship with an employer after resigning?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/92/how-do-i-maintain-a-good-relationship-with-an-employer-after-resigning)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't try and psychoanalyse your boss, it's not constructive at this point. You have one foot out the door, focus on where your life and career are heading. Not where they have been.

Don't worry about your boss being a bit upset, it's understandable enough. Just remain friendly and professional until you're out the door with a good reference.

Comment: That's right, I don't know what made me think like I should care, thanks for the heads-up

Comment: Perfect, concise answer.

Answer (score -4):

Thirty days notice is nuts. You know how much notice you get if they fire you? Zero days notice.

If you want to stick out the whole month, and they do not appreciate that, I think that is pretty telling of the kind of people you are dealing with.

Comment: The notice period - on both sides - will be set out in the contract.

Comment: The OP is from Connecticut, so I don't think Dutch employment law is relevant here.

Comment: You're totally right, but the company I work for is not that dickish, but I don't get why people disliked your answer so much

Comment: @Mr.Derpinthoughton Because it's not moral. Some companies might be evil, but not all of them are. If we start behaving like all of them are evil, we are not working towards a better future but a worst one. Try to be nice by default.